# after deploy:update_code not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano

I have my application inside a subfolder on my dcm, because of that when `capistrano` updates the code on my servers i need to correct the contents of the release.

I am using `capistrano v 2.15.5` and i don't want to move to `v3`

I tried to add a hook to `deploy:update_code` a `before` will call my custom task, but a `after` never is called.

i tried also hook to `deploy:finalize_update` but this time `after` or `before` are never called.

What should i do?

**EDIT**

Small update i manage to add a hook to `before 'deploy:assets:symlink'` its not what i want but for now should work.

Why some tasks accept hooks and others don't?